# Unable to type in Ubuntu terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server

I am new to programming and use Ubuntu’s terminal on Visual Studio Code. The terminal is blank with a blinking cursor and won't let me type anything. Any tips on troubleshooting this? I didn't make any changes; this seems to have happened out of the blue.

[image: black window titled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

Comment: Is that your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913373/9454010

Comment: Hey, nope mine was blank. But resolved it by uninstalling and then reinstalling Ubuntu. thank you